# C++ client to connect to non blocking Java NIO server

Tags: java, c++, client, server, nio

I was wondering how, if possible, could the task of creating/emulating a java serversocket in C++ be performed? I'm new to C++ but I'm fairly proficient in Java. My server (written in java) needs to receive data from all both Java/C++ clients (data is transferred using JSON Strings) but I'm not sure how to establish a connection in C++ with the NIO Server.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by reading the following man pages:

```
socket(2)
bind(2)
listen(2)
accept(2)
connect(2)
```

After you determine whether you need to create a server or a client-side socket, you will then proceed to implement it using the appropriate combination of these system calls.

A socket is a socket. Whether or not the other end of the socket is an application written in Java, C++, Perl, Ruby, or any other language, it makes no difference. All sockets are created the same way. It does make a difference in terms of the format of the data exchanged across the socket, but looks like you have that covered.